# Do Lie groups in bundle automorphisms have corresponding principal bundles?

Tags: differential-geometry, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

Given some theory described by fields from a vector bundle $E$, with section $\phi \in \Gamma(E)$, we get that transformations on the fields are part of the automorphisms on that bundle, ie, $\Phi \in \text{Aut}(E)$. Such a transformation is a symmetry if

$$S[\phi] = S[\Phi(\phi)]$$

Obviously there are many such symmetries in general, but generally we are interested in the Lie groups, ie, a subgroup $G$ of $\text{Aut}(E)$ such that $G$ forms a Lie group. In which case we generally work from here with the principal bundle $P$ made from the group $G$.

If, given an action functional $S$, we have a Lie subgroup $G \subset \text{Aut}(E)$ such that $S$ is invariant under the action of this group, does this guarantee the existence of a principal bundle $G$ over $M$, with the appropriate action on the other fields of $E$?

I'm guessing this would probably depend on the domain of integration of $S$ as there may be global obstructions to such a thing, but if let's say the domain of $S$ was the entire manifold for instance, would such a thing be guarantee? I suspect this may also only apply to vertical automorphisms here because I don't think translations for instance have appropriate principal bundles for them.